# Dashboard with React and WebSockets - How to structure the app

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am building a dashboard with React.js. The dashboard will receive messages containing certain realtime data via a WebSocket every about 1s. On the dashboard there will be different kinds of widgets to display that data. Certain widgets will only display a certain type of data e.g. widget A will only display data(A) and widget B will only display data(B). Which type of data is contained in a message can be determined by the message type.

My current idea is to put the WebSocket in a component way up the component tree. That component will save the different message types in respective fields in its state object and will pass that field as a prop to the widget that requires it.

My problem with this approach is that it does not seem to be a good idea to have all the data way up in the tree although the only component that is interested in a certain type might be way down.

My actual idea was, that widgets can register to a certain event that is fired whenever a message is received via the WebSocket and they can decide for themselves if they are interested in that message or not. But React does not seem to provide such a mechanism.

So, what would you suggest how to structure that app and especially how to get the data to the widgets?

Comment: why dont you query of the data when the widget is mounted?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have said that the device sends realtime data that is sent by the device every about 1s. Querying the data one time when the component is mounted would not be enough.

Comment: I assume the object which is used to handle the socket i/o operations. In your receive message handler whenever you receive an update from the server, dispatch an action which would update the correct variable in store with the new data. As you components are subscribing to the changes your UI will re-render and show the changes